# What vulnerabilities are there in a custom react-based e-commerce website and why should I just use Shopify?

Tags: security, shopify, e-commerce

I have been programming a small e-commerce platform to sell jewelry.
Initially I wanted to make it web3 compatible ( accept meta mask payments ) and given that I work as a dev I wanted to take the DIY approach as opposed to platforms like Shopify specifically.

Now that I’m getting closer to finishing the website , I contemplate to myself - should I just switch to using Shopify instead ? My contemplation stems from unknown vulnerabilities that I am anticipate ..

My site uses Stripesnd paypal for payments. I don’t save any other data besides order info and shipping address .

Is there any underlying vulnerabilities that Shopify takes care of that I’m not thinking of ?

It seems simple enough to take payments on a site but I have a feeling I am not thinking about some major implications of not using a platform like Shopify .

On one hand I’d really like to use my own website given all the time I’ve spent making it ( also like my front end design better than any template I’ve seen ) so this post is for people to give me their perspective on both pros and cons so I can decide whether I just neeed to dump my work and start over with Shopify or continue on the way forward with DIY coming out as hero ;)

Thanks In advance fam

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible to make your own website and make it secure enough, somebody made Shopify too after all. :) It is also easily possible to leave vulnerabilies in your code that then get exploited. The problem is that if you don't have a good grasp of what you should have even looked at, it will be quite challenging to actually get it right.

You should be aware of potential code level vulnerabilities, and use secure coding and architecture principles to structure and code your website. OWASP is a great resource that helps with learning about those. Higher level principles include things like least privilege, segregation of duties, defense in depth, minimizing attack surface, secure defaults, failing securely and so on. Actual code level vulnerabilities include things like SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), cross-site request forgery (CSRF), tampering with parameters, session management errors, authentication or authorization errors and so on, there is *a lot* of these. And your 3rd party libraries that you included can (and will) also have some of these, how will you discover that, and will you have the capacity to keep up with latest versions?

When hosting your own service (even in an IaaS cloud environment like AWS EC2), that brings its own challenges in terms of security too - you need to care about the ops side of security as well. Things like would you even notice if there's an attack? Would you know what to do if a customer called with their money spent on things they didn't buy? Would you have forensic evidence to prove if they are actually lying? :)

You can use tools to scan for some of these vulnerabilities, but that will never be comprehensive - actually, nothing will. Automated tools are very useful, but will miss a lot of things. You can also buy penetration testing services, some of those are really good (and some not), they will find vulnerabilities the same way attackers would - but those are quite expensive.

However, having said all this, the most important thing is to keep your defenses proportionate to the risk. This basically means you don't want to spend more on securing your website than the maximum amount you may lose in case of a compromise. Outsourcing payments to Stripe or Paypal is a great start, because if you have the integration correctly set up, you likely already limited the maximum possible loss quite a bit.

So should you code an ecommerce website yourself, and sell stuff? In the light of the above, it's very opinionated, but I think why not, just consider the above, manage your risks, learn about potential vulnerabilities, mitigate them the best you can, and prepare for things to go wrong. In the end, it's probably cheaper to just use a ready-made service, though a lot less fun. :)

Comment: Couldn’t ask for a better response. Thanks Gabor. Do you know of any consultation services I could use to get an analysis done on my website ?  Maybe someone can just take a look and see if there’s anything obvious I would need to fix

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you should... and you can use any SaaS eCommerce platform: Shopify or BigCommerce or Snipkart without giving up your DIY custom features, because those platforms can be used as a headless eCommerce platform.
This way you don't have risks around managing backend and data (platform will do this, and not loosing the custom features and fine-tuned customer experience you implemented yourself)